# making post request with createAsyncThunk redux toolkit

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Following is my reduxtoolkit code. I am trying to post data but it is giving me 422 error. The response says spot_id and item_id required but I am sending it. Am i doing anthing wrong?

```
export const postData = createAsyncThunk(
  'items/addItem',
  async (data, thunk) => {
    const accessToken = await getStorageValue("accessToken")
    const axios = await axiosMaker()

    const newItem = new FormData()
    newItem.append("spot_id", data.spotId)
    newItem.append("item_id", JSON.stringify(data.itemId))
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('add_item',newItem , {
            headers: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
        })
        console.log("it is success",response.data)
        return response.data
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("it is failure",error)
        return thunk.rejectWithValue("error")
    }
}
```

)

Comment: Have you inspected (browser devtools) what the payload of your post request looks like? Is the backend really requiring form data (kind of outdated) and not just a JSON payload?

Comment: I checked in with the inspector before the API request. I can see the data there. The endpoint is working from postman but not in my code.  However, when I changed the data format it is working. Instead of form data, I used the following format
{ spot_id: data.spotId, kit_id: JSON.stringify(data.kitId) } and it is working. But, why the FormData in postman working but not in the above code.